# Can I use 6 wire direct burial for 200 amp service box?

Tags: electrical, service

Hi I’m trying to turn a shed into a small apartment. I have 200 ft 6 wire running from pole to 100 amp breaker box in shed [ future apt]. On the pole I have a 200 amp service box with meter space. Is it ok to connect the 6 and call electric company out to put in meter or should I down grade to a 4 wire?

Comment: I have no idea if you're talking about a 6-wire feeder or a 6-gauge feeder with 3 or 4 wires.  And there's still not enough information in this question.  Are you talking about a commercial property with a shed for rent?

Comment: You would have to get with the power company about the meter issues.

Comment: In the world of wire gauges smaller numbers correspond to heavier conductors. Not sure what a "down grade to a 4 wire" means. I wouldn't expect the slope, either up or down, over a 200 foot run to have a significant effect on the current carrying capacity of the wire (for AC service).

Comment: @HABO The OP is obviously not talking about slopes. From context they clearly meant "downgrade" as in "switch to a lower wire gauge number" (meaning increase the wire size, which most people would call an "upgrade").

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use either #6 or #4 wire for a 100A service. #2 is the absolute smallest that could be used for 100A service in certain circumstances, but you're going to need a larger cable at that distance.  Exactly what cable you need is going to depend on whether it's copper or aluminum, what the temperature rating is, and what your acceptable voltage drop is.  Call an electrician.